# Different patterns in dataset

Tags: feature-selection, algorithms

Suppose some features in a dataset have a linear correlation with the target variable, some have a polynomial correlation, and for categorical features, the target values tend to distribute differently across classes. What should we do in such a situation? Should we create separate models for each scenario and then average their outputs, for instance? Or is there a way to handle all of these cases simultaneously?

One approach that comes to mind is using decision trees or random forests. However, wouldn't that be a waste of the linear or polynomial correlation with the target values?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can only tell after you've tried. I think you'd find that information reassuring, since you mentioned you're in the early stages of learning.

To address your specific questions, I think the first thing to do is to separate your categorical features -- unless you're using decision trees or some variation. Because you won't be able to effectively use them for most modeling techniques.

For the multiple patterns that appear, you may want to increase the strength of your model. Probably prioritize looking into using a kernel-embedded model (e.g., SVM or neural networks).

It's not uncommon, although it may demand some extra work, to train an ensemble of independent models, each corresponding to a specific feature type (i.e., data modality) and combine the outputs in the final stage. Combining the outputs can be done in two ways:

- heuristics (e.g., average/mean predictions)
- trained ensemble/fusion model (e.g., logistic regression)

The latter requires a third dataset were you can train the parameters required to combine predictions from your model outputs and return the target value.